# Any NIO frameworks for .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, frameworks, nio

Are there any non-blocking IO frameworks for .NET?

I am looking for something similar to what [Apache Mina](http://mina.apache.org/) and [JBoss Netty](http://www.jboss.org/netty) provides for Java: a framework for implementing highly scalable servers - not just the low-level support that the .NET framework provides.

**EDIT:** To better explain what I would like to see, here is a basic example of what you can do with Mina:

In Mina I can implement a ProtocolDecoder like this:

```
public class SimpleDecoder extends CumulativeProtocolDecoder {
  protected boolean doDecode(IoSession session, IoBuffer in, ProtocolDecoderOutput out) throws Exception {
    if (in.remaining() < 4) 
      return false;
    int length = in.getInt();
    if(in.remaining() < 4 + length)
      return false;
    Command command = new Command(in.asInputStream());
    out.write(command);
  }
}
```

And a CommandHandler like this:

```
public abstract class CommandHandler extends IoHandlerAdapter{
  public void messageReceived(IoSession session, Object message) throws IOException, CloneNotSupportedException {
    Command command = (Command) message;
    // Handle command. Probably by putting it in a workqueue.
  }
}
```

If I start the server by calling

```
CommandHandler handler = new CommandHandler();
NioSocketAcceptor acceptor = new NioSocketAcceptor();
acceptor.getFilterChain().addLast("protocol", new ProtocolCodecFilter(new SimpleDecoder(false)));
acceptor.setLocalAddress(new InetSocketAddress(port));
acceptor.setHandler(handler);
acceptor.bind();
```

I will get a non-blocking server.

It will run a single (or at least just a few) threads, cycling through all incoming connections, gathering data from the sockets, and call `SimpleDecoder.doDecode()` to see if it has a complete command on the connection. Then it will pass the command to `CommandHandler.messageReceived()`, and I can take over the processing.

Comment: Non-blocking I/O has been part of .NET since day 1. What are you looking for,exactly?

Comment: I am looking for a server-framework on top of the low-level calls in .NET.

Comment: I don't know enough about Java to know why something like MINA would be helpful. But async access is built into every level of .NET. It's in WCF, ADO.NET, Workflow - everywhere. I looked at the MINA page and see no value in .NET for anything they said on that page.

Comment: Maybe you could give us some idea of the kind of program you need to write. Don't assume that something like MINA is required to do that.

Comment: Are you looking for ASP.NET's support for asynchronous pages? Allowing an async-operation to complete while allowing the original processing thread to process other HTTP requests and then picking up the original request when the async-operation completes?

Comment: Here is a well designed NIO framework for Java: http://www.jboss.org/netty. I'm looking for an equivalent for .Net (and I supposed that Rasmus do too). It's not just asynchronous IO but a framework on top which simplifies development greatly.

Comment: If you're looking for a high-performance socket server for .NET, there is Helios https://github.com/helios-io/helios which is very good, however it is now deprecated and the latest work is on DotNetty https://github.com/azure/dotnetty which is a full port of Java's Netty and started by the Microsoft Azure team.

Comment: Havent tried it but look at https://github.com/Azure/DotNetty/blob/dev/README.md

Answer (score 7):

You can take a look at SuperSocket, http://supersocket.codeplex.com/
It may not be strong like Mina and Netty, but it is kind of simple framework you can use easily.

Answer (score 3):

There is the [XF.Server](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/high-performance-server.aspx), which [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/319732/tips-techniques-for-high-performance-c-server-sockets) says is flaky. This last question offers advice about how to write high performing networking code in .NET (use async sockets, etc.)

There's also a preview of [C# Network Programming](http://books.google.com/books?id=mHT-_P_jKQcC) on Google Books which discusses, among other things, asynchronous socket calls.

This [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc300760.aspx) is also interesting, but gets you no closer to an actual framework.

Comment: Thanks for your info, especially the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/319732/tips-techniques-for-high-performance-c-server-sockets

Answer (score 0):

You can use Mina directly in .Net via [ikvm](http://www.ikvm.net/).

Comment: People using Mina are looking for high performance. Do you think mina used with ikvm will perform well ?

Comment: Generally non-blocking IO does not necessarily give better performance, but better scalability. Non-blocking socket IO prevents the need for a thread per connection. Servicing many connections on a single thread reduces the memory and context switch overhead of multiple threads. Since nio operations are IO bound and not CPU bound, I suspect, but have not evidence, that any overhead introduced by ivkm is negligible.