# What's the replacement for Java NIO in .NET 4.5?

Tags: c#, .net

As I studied NIO, one of its important features is its non-blocking behavior.
Is it true that in .NET and C# the combinations of Async/Await and Streams brings that non-blocking feature of NIO into .NET?

Or is there any other good replacement in .NET 4.5?

I found [Any NIO frameworks for .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/648282/any-nio-frameworks-for-net) question on SO but it's a 2009 question which there wasn't any `Async/Await` introduced yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from `async/await`, the other framework (well more of a extension) is the [`Rx Extensions`](https://rx.codeplex.com/) (Reactive Extensions)

Few Helpful links

- Rx Homepage - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/data/gg577609.aspx
- [101 Rx Samples](http://rxwiki.wikidot.com/101samples)

Rx extension has little learning curve, but it can really ease up few works

As described on the website

> The Reactive Extensions (Rx) is a library for composing asynchronous
>   and event-based programs using observable sequences and LINQ-style
>   query operators. Using Rx, developers represent asynchronous data
>   streams with Observables, query asynchronous data streams using LINQ
>   operators, and parameterize the concurrency in the asynchronous data
>   streams using Schedulers. Simply put, Rx = Observables + LINQ +
>   Schedulers.
>
> Whether you are authoring a traditional desktop or web-based
>   application, you have to deal with asynchronous and event-based
>   programming from time to time. Desktop applications have I/O
>   operations and computationally expensive tasks that might take a long
>   time to complete and potentially block other active threads.
>   Furthermore, handling exceptions, cancellation, and synchronization is
>   difficult and error-prone.

Answer (score 0):

The best and closest match is :https://github.com/Aaronontheweb/helios, it is an equivalent port of the Netty framework for java.